# how to add file php to tpl in scripts

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, smarty

I want to put php file to tpl
The following code

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "1_1";
$password = "1=~Eh]V";
$dbname = "11_11";


// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT domain FROM insights_base WHERE domain_1 = current_date() ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     echo "<table><tr><th>Domain Name</th></tr>";
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo "<tr>

<td>" . $row["domain"]. " </td>

         </tr>";
     }
     echo "</table>";
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}`enter code here`
$conn->close();
?>
```

Files path

require_once $current_dir . '/app.config.php';

require_once $current_dir . '/lib/smarty/Smarty.class.php';

require_once $current_dir . '/lib/classes/Database.singleton.php';

require_once $current_dir . '/function_core.php';

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: HOW TO ADD THIS CODE TO TPL

Comment: You want the result from the php file inside your tpl ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

index.php:

```
<?php

require 'libs/Smarty.class.php';

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "1_1";
$password = "1=~Eh]V";
$dbname = "11_11";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql = "SELECT domain FROM insights_base WHERE domain_1 = current_date() ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$data = array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       $data[] = $row;
    }
}
$conn->close();

$smarty = new Smarty;
$smarty->assign('data', $data);
$smarty->display('index.tpl');
```

index.tpl:

```
<table>
    <tr><th>Domain Name</th></tr>
    {foreach from=$data key=k item=i}
        <tr>
            <td>{$i.domain}</td>
        </tr>
    {/foreach}
</table>
```

More information and examples you can find [here](https://github.com/smarty-php/smarty).

Comment: You can tweak similar example here: http://runnable.com/VW3rNfaqEfFieU7F/smarty-for-php